# New Vue component is not find on Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I started working with vue in laravel. But after I make new component and use it in my blade template its not showing. cleared all the cache from browser. checked for different solution but nothing was helpful.

```
import quickreplies from './components/PageList.vue';

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#chatleads',
    components : {
        quickreplies
    }
});
```

The commented line is still working even if I delete this. example-component is working. This is weird.

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

in my default layout

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Can anyone please show me a way on how to overcome this?

NB: I am using vagrant in windows.

Comment: Are you running `npm run watch`? Are you sure you're recompiling your assets after you make changes?

Comment: yes. I am running npm run watch and also tried with npm run dev. but nothing helps. here you can find a screenshot. https://s17.postimg.org/k856wbtsv/screenshot_37.jpg

Comment: run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: did that. but its also not working

Comment: did you try to restart the dev server?, i mean stopping webpack and starting again

Comment: oh yes. I did that

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you add your css and js files in blade template? Maybe you add default files? And also what's about your webpack.config.js file? Can you show it?

Comment: yes i update my codes in here and this is the full code of default layout. https://pastebin.com/q1RyqZC6

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `version` method:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version();
```

It will add special prefix at the file name and will load new file(not from browser cache). [versioning](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

Comment: Can you display the network tab? With loaded js file.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why u are having that error is because of your Laravel, npm and node Version. I actually had this issued, searched for a solution for days. Until I figured it out. So 
1) I downgraded my Laravel to 5.4 from 5.6 to test
2) I upgraded my npm and Node.
3) I install cross-env
4) I ran Npm install
5) I ran npm run dev
6) I ran npm run warch

After these stepes, it worked perfectly. So I think you need to look at the versions